# Microsoft Azure Django SQL connection w/ ADO.NET

Tags: python, sql-server, django, azure

I'm currently following this tutorial to build a Django web app that uses the Azure SQL database: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-ptvs-django-sql

I'm on the step for "Configure the Project", where I'm supposed to paste the connection string in settings.py. (I'm using Visual Studios, with Python Tools). The string is in this format:

```
Server=<ServerName>,<ServerPort>;Database=<DatabaseName>;User ID=<UserName>;Password={your_password_here};Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

However, when I try to do a Django migrate, I get an invalid syntax error.

- When I copy the ADO.NET string from Azure, the server name has "tcp:"    in front i.e. tcp:myserver.database.windows.net, am I supposed to include the "tcp:"? It seems like it's triggering an error.
- Are the spaces in the parameter titles (like "User ID" and "Connection    Timeout") causing an error?

Pretty new to using Django / Azure SQL so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On Azure portal, you can get the connection string for SQL Database as the figure below.

[image]

For Django/other frameworks in Python, you need to copy the connecting string for OBDC like below.

> Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:**<server-host-name>**.database.windows.net,1433;Database=**<db-name>**;Uid=**<user>@<server-host-name>>**;Pwd=**<your_password_here>**;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;

If using PTVS in VS to develop the Django App in Python, the first thing is to add the required package `pyodbc` in the `requirements.txt` file. You can refer to [the section `Managing Required Packages` of PTVS wiki page](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Python-Environments#managing-required-packages) to know how to do it.

Then, you need to configure the `settings.py` file of Django web project via add the connection information from the ODBC connection string above, as below.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': '<db-name>',
        'USER': '<user>',
        'PASSWORD': '<your_password_here>',
        'HOST': '<server-host-name>',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
            'MARS_Connection': 'True',
        }
    }
}
```

All these above are introduced in [the section `Configure the Project` of the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-python-ptvs-django-sql#configure-the-project). These connection configuration information for Django are as the same as them in the ADO.NET connecting string.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.